# How to display a banner in a PWA when an update is available and when the device is offline?

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

can help me create a simple PWA for my site. Currently the installation banner appears and it works.

1. I want that when I update my site, a message is displayed in the application in the form of a banner with the text "An update is available, click on this banner to update".
2. I want that when the internet network is not available, a banner appears with the message "You are offline, the content of this page may be obsolete".

How can I do this ? Thank you

[image]

[image]

Here are the files I created :

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr" class="h-100">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/example/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body class="d-flex flex-column bg-dark text-white text-center">

    <div>MY PAGE</div>

    <script src="bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
      .then(reg => {
        console.log('Service worker registered! ', reg);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(' Service worker registration failed: ', err);
      });
  });
}
```

sw.js

```
const staticCacheName = 'v10';
const filesToCache = [
  '/',
  '/index.html',
  '/style.css',
  '/app.js',
  '/bootstrap.min.css',
  '/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
  '/favicon.ico',
  '/logo.png',
  '/icon-144.png',
  '/icon-192.png',
  '/icon-512.png',
  '/ipadpro1_splash.png',
  '/ipadpro2_splash.png',
  '/ipadpro3_splash.png',
  '/ipad_splash.png',
  '/iphone5_splash.png',
  '/iphone6_splash.png',
  '/iphoneplus_splash.png',
  '/iphonexr_splash.png',
  '/iphonexsmax_splash.png',
  '/iphonex_splash.png'
];

self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticCacheName).then(cache => {
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  event.waitUntil(caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
    return Promise.all(
      cacheNames.filter(function(staticCacheName) {
      }).map(function(staticCacheName) {
        return caches.delete(staticCacheName);
      })
    );
  }));
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request).then(cachedResponse => {
    if (cachedResponse) {
      return cachedResponse;
    }
    return fetch(event.request);
  }));
});

self.addEventListener('message', event => {
  if (event.data.action === 'skipWaiting') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});
```